# All value fields are changing to the same value if I change one input in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, formik

This is my code:

```
{
    lining.hitprescription ?
    <div className="prescription-form">
        {
            medicine.map((item, index) => {
                return <>
                    <div className="form-items" key={index}>
                        <label htmlFor="name">Medicine {index + 1}:</label>
                        <input className="prescription-input"{...formik.getFieldProps("medicine")}></input>
                    </div>
                </>
             })
         }
         <div className="form-items" onClick={addMoreMedicine}>
             <label htmlFor="addmore" style={{ color: "blue" }}>Add More <Add></Add></label>
         </div>
    </div>: null
}
```

inside react JSX, I am mapping the input form fields where medicine is initialized as

```
const [medicine, setmedicine] = useState(["", ""])
```

and I am using formik where values are initialized as

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
        basicInfo: '',
        labTestId: [],
        appointmentId: null,
        medicine: ""
    },
    validate: values => {
        let errors = {}
        if (!values.basicInfo) {
            errors.basicInfo = "Required!"
        }
        return errors
    }
})
```

the problem I get is if I change one input field then the same value is shown in other input fields during the time of changing field , how to solve this problem?

Comment: how many inputs do u have? i only see one input in your code pls specify

Comment: @AhmedHosny all specify correct. You can see in JSX `medicine.map` when `const [medicine, setmedicine] = useState(["", ""])`  array with 2 empty strings. Conclusion: 2 inputs

Answer (score 1):

This behavior because you set state `medicine` with type `array` to each input. When
you map array of medicine you must set state by `index` for each input . Example:

```
{...formik.getFieldProps("medicine")[index]}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-johnson-11klz)